# VBS pharser in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, random, vbscript, xls, xlsx

Hello i have a XLS sheet of 1.000 rows. I must extract 30 rows random with almost a city and copy in other sheet. I have tried but i am going crazy.

i begin write this script but i need help.

```
Sub emp_to_dept()
Dim wks As Worksheet
    Windows("Sales.xls").Activate
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        wks.Copy After:=Workbooks("SampleSheet.xls").Sheets(1)
    Next
    Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here there is a sample of some rows.

[image]

Comment: Please rephrase "with almost a city" ... it's unclear what you mean

Comment: What does that code snippet have to do with collecting 30 random entries?

Comment: Mike i intend that all cities must been selected almost one time.

Comment: Jeeped i think code must restart all new

Answer (score 0):

referring to :

> sheet of 1.000 rows. I must extract 30 rows random

and assuming the "1000" data is in column A with A1 as the 1st item. Just put this and drag down for 10 rows

```
=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1,1000))
```

/(^_^)